# vim-python-mode: No module named __future__

Tags: python, vim

I've installed [vim python-mod](http://github.com/klen/python-mode)
and getting the following error:

```
Error detected while processing [..]/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/pymode/virtualenv.vim:
line    3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[..]/.vim/bundle/python-mode/pymode/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

`python --version` => `Python 2.7.9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you. To fix it, I removed Vim and reinstalled it again.

With brew(OSX) you can run:

```
$ brew remove vim
$ brew install vim
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thx, but it didn't help

Comment: Fixed for me. I went from system python to brew python, and this was my fix. Thanks, André!

Comment: I've managed with `brew uninstall --force vim; brew install vim`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was lucky to remember that I had recently brew installed a package that pulled in python as a dependency. Adjusting my path to load the previous python first works. In my case:

`PATH=path/to/home/bin:/path/to/brew/vim/bin:/path/to/system/python/bin:<all-other-paths>`

Comment: Thanks, but my vim and python are both in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Here's my path: /Users/USER/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1090/bin/:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin  It loads my vim from homebrew since it's earlier in the path. It then loads the system python from /usr/bin before loading everything else from the regular system PATH.